# Need help in transforming this SQL statement to GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

```
    select
        b.security_type,
        b.symbol,
        b.security_description,
        b.trade_date_qty as 'axys_qty',
        c.trade_date_qty as 'fidelity_qty',
        c.trade_date_qty - b.trade_date_qty as 'qty_diff',
        b.cost_basis as 'axys_cost',
        c.cost_basis as 'fidelity_cost',
        c.cost_basis - b.cost_basis as 'cost_diff'
    from
        account a
        inner join advent_position b on a.fixed_account_number = b.account_number
        inner join fidelity_position c on a.fixed_account_number = c.account_number and b.symbol = c.symbol
    where
        b.account_number = '636296651'
```

Basically, I have the ff. domains: Account, AdventPosition, FidelityPosition. I haven't set the relationship yet. I'm just wondering if there's a way to replicate the logic above using Criteria or HQL. Forgive me, I'm still new to Grails.

Thank you for any leads on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be something close to this:

```
String hql = '''
select
   b.securityType,
   b.symbol,
   b.securityDescription,
   b.tradeDateQty,
   c.tradeDateQty,
   c.tradeDateQty - b.tradeDateQty,
   b.costBasis,
   c.costBasis,
   c.costBasis - b.costBasis
from
   Account a, AdventPosition b, FidelityPosition c
where
   a.fixedAccountNumber = b.accountNumber
   and a.fixedAccountNumber = c.accountNumber
   and b.symbol = c.symbol
   and b.accountNumber = :accountNumber
'''

def accountNumber = '636296651'
def results = Account.executeQuery(hql, [accountNumber: accountNumber])
```

The results will be an ArrayList of Object[], so you can iterate it with something like

```
for (row in results) {
   def securityType = row[0]
   def symbol = row[1]
   def securityDescription = row[2]
   def axys_qty = row[3]
   def fidelity_qty = row[4]
   def qty_diff = row[5]
   def axys_cost = row[6]
   def fidelity_cost = row[7]
   def cost_diff = row[8]
}
```

I replaced the hard-coded account number with a named parameter; you can use regular ? like in SQL if you prefer and run 'def results = Account.executeQuery(hql, [accountNumber])', and of course if you intented it to be hard-coded then restore that and don't pass in the 2nd parameter, just run 'def results = Account.executeQuery(hql)'

Answer (score 0):

just sharing the solution that I came up (while waiting for an answer :P) but note that the previous answer is way much better and faster:

```
def acc = Account.findByFixedAccountNumber('636296651')
List advPos = AdventPosition.findAllByAccountNumber('636296651')
List fidPos = advPos.collect {
    FidelityPosition.findAllByAccountNumberAndSymbol('636296651', it.symbol)
}

def item = [:]
def res = []

def limit = advPos.size() - 1
for(i in 0..limit){
    item.security_type = advPos[i].securityType
    item.symbol = advPos[i].symbol
    item.security_description = advPos[i].securityDescription
    item.axys_qty = advPos[i].tradeDateQty
    item.fidelity_qty = fidPos[i].tradeDateQty
    item.qty_diff = item.fidelity_qty - item.axys_qty
    item.axys_cost = advPos[i].costBasis
    item.fidelity_cost = fidPos[i].costBasis
    item.cost_diff = item.fidelity_cost - item.axys_cost 
    res.add(item)
}
```